# sending message in specific guild+channel in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make my bot send the link of every guild it joins to a specific guild and specific channel but its not working can someone help me .

```py
async def on_guild_join(guild):
  link = await guild.text_channels[0].create_invite(max_age=0)
  channel = 812711315608305664
  guild = 810639381647065099
  await guild.channel.send(str(link))
```

Comment: Do you have any other feedback besides `it's not working`?

Comment: yeah thats why i am posting it

Comment: You're overwriting the `guild` variable with a number. Is that supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `guild` with a number.

If you want to send something in a channel of a guild (and assuming that the `guild` parameter in the function call is a [`discord.Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild)), you should be able to get the channel using
[`guild.get_channel(812711315608305664)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel) (assuming that this is the ID of the channel)
This gives you a `discord.GuildChannel` object which is, however, abstract. If it is of type [`discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel) , you could call the method [`send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send).